# Is there a way to archive an email in Gmail once it has been read?

Tags: gmail

I have dozens of filters which label my incoming mail and archive them, but I've begun to think that I would prefer it if the filters did not auto-archive, and instead just labelled the email and dropped them in the inbox, with the added extra that once they are read, they are then archived.

Is there any way to achieve this in GMail? Any labs features maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have an email open, there will be an Archive button. If you have keyboard shortcuts enabled, you can hit "e" or "y" to archive the email.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what the *Priority inbox* feature does for you.
With this feature switched on, the first section of your inbox will show all unread mail (regardless of labels):

[image: Screenshot of the Priority Inbox]

Once you have read a message, it is removed from that section.

To switch on *Priority inbox*, click *Gear icon → Settings → Inbox*, find the *Inbox type* drop-down menu, and select *Priority inbox*.
[image: Screenshot showing the Inbox Type drop-down menu]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Script to write a piece of code that is going to check regularly (every 2 hours for instance) if an email has been read or not.

By doing so, you could write a rule which will archive all emails matching these criteria.

There is the Google Script official help:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support

And here is my own post about auto-archiving process in Gmail:
https://medium.com/@fw3d/auto-archive-emails-in-gmail-after-2-days-1ebf0e076b1c#.n6lmwlqjm